# Could/should I organize my 30 classes in folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have about 30 classes in my Rails app, and if feels a bit like a clutter visually.

Out of these 30 classes there are 3 sets of 5 classes each that are so independent function-wise in the application that it would feel natural to put those in a folder each.

Is this possible and recommendable, or is there any other way to organize my files?

Comment: I do it all the time, so yes I recommend it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally it is possible and it is advised to do so - code organization is a key to any successful project.

In rails each folder within any load_path defines an (initially) empty module, so remember that classes within a file `subfolder/my_class.rb` are expected to be named `Subfolder::MyClass` rather than `MyClass` - otherwise rails will not be able to find them.

Another way would be to add your folders to `load_paths`, however personally I much rather prefer to have my scoped classes to be, well, scoped within a modules.

To this you'll need to add the following to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.load_paths << config.root.join 'app', 'models', '**'
```

Comment: And henceforth, when referencing this class anywhere in my app, I need to prepend it with the subfolder name? If so, there isn't any other way to namespace my models that (more or less) only involves putting the classes in the same folder?

Comment: To build on the earlier question, what parts in my Rails would I need to update following the suggested pattern?